# Update field on `customer_entity` table

Tags: magento2, attributes, customer

I created a new field on `customer_entity` table.

```
 $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $setup->getTable('customer_entity'),
            'profession',
            [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'comment' => 'Profession',
                'nullable' => false,
                'default' => false,
            ]
        );
```

Now I need to update this field. I'm trying

```
    use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerExtractor as CustomerExtractor;

    $customer = $this->customerExtractor->extract('customer_account_create', $this->_request);
    $customer->setCustomAttribute('profession','test');
```

but the field on table stay blank. 
No error appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a repo [adding a new customer attribute](https://bitbucket.org/magstaging/newcustomerattribute) that is public.

if you take a look you will see the attribute needs to be added to customers form as well as attribute set. Hope this repo gives you some ideas to resolve your issue

Answer (score -1):

**Try below Code**

```
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerExtractor as CustomerExtractor;

    $customer = $this->customerExtractor->extract('customer_account_create', $this->_request);
    $customer->setProfession('test');
    $customer->save();
```

***I hope it help..!!!***

Comment: this way i got a php error

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\\Customer\\Model\\Data\\Customer::setProfession() in /var/www/html/saccaro/app/code/BVZ/Customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php:362\nStack trace:\n#0

Comment: please add that error here.

Comment: [Wed Dec 26 14:17:06.359291 2018] [php7:error] [pid 11340] [client ::1:47130] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\\Customer\\Model\\Data\\Customer::setProfession() in /var/www/html/saccaro/app/code/BVZ/Customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php:362\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/saccaro/generated/code/BVZ/Customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost/Interceptor.php(24): BVZ\\Customer\\Controller\\Account\\CreatePost->execute()\n#1